# SQL Totaling by Day

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a simple query that spits out new_users by day...

```
Select trunc(create_dtime),Count(Player_Id) as New_Users
  From Player
 Where Trunc(Create_Dtime) >= To_Date('2011-APR-22','yyyy-mon-dd')
 Group By Trunc(Create_Dtime)
 Order by trunc(Create_Dtime)
```

I would like this to total the new_users as each day goes on...so for example if with the current query spits out a result with:

```
Apr 22
Apr 23
Apr 24 of 1000 new users each day...
```

I want this new query to say:

```
Apr 22 = 1000 New users
Apr 23 = 2000
Apr 24 = 3000
```

...and so on until the very last date(today) has the total number of new users in one single row.

Let me know if this is clear enough.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a "Running total". See: [Oracle Rolling or Running totals by month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931975/oracle-rolling-or-running-totals-by-month)

Comment: @DanJ you missed `in one single row` and `totalling by day`.

Comment: @Annjawn Given that the accepted answer below is roughly identical to the accepted answer in the question I linked, I stand by my recommendation. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this using a cumulative sum, which Oracle happily supports through the analytic functions:

```
select thedate, New_Users,
       sum(New_Users) over (order by thedate) as Cumulative_New_Users
from (Select trunc(create_dtime) as thedate, Count(Player_Id) as New_Users
      From Player
      Where Trunc(Create_Dtime) >= To_Date('2011-APR-22','yyyy-mon-dd')
      Group By Trunc(Create_Dtime)
     ) t
Order by 1
```

Comment: Gordon, exactly what I was looking for. It seems as though this "over(order by)" language is the key factor. Appreciate it.

Comment: Oracle is no longer the only database that supports this syntax.  SQL Server also supports it, and some other databases have other ways of getting cumulative sums.  It is amazing that it took more than 20 years after the first standard to start seeing this key functionality in databases.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: SQL Server's support for windowing functions (the ANSI standard's name for that) was very limited before SQL Server 2012 (e.g. SQL Server 2008 and before does **not** support cumulative sums like this). Btw: PostgreSQL was the first OpenSource DBMS to fully support windowing functions (even a bit more than Oracle)